# Equivalent http request of curl command

Tags: http, curl, oauth

I'm working on OAUTH 2.0 stuff using following curl command which is working fine in my terminal.

command -

```
curl -u testclient1:testpass1 http://localhost/oauth2-server/token.php -d 'grant_type=password&username=bshaffer&password=brent123'
```

I want to know what's equivalent HTTP request for above CURL command so that, i can use guzzle(comparatively easier) to make HTTP request to get the token. I've tried a lot of combination but not getting the right way to do it.

Comment: You could use a packet sniffer, like Wireshark, to see the actual HTTP requests that curl is sending.

Answer (score 2):

finally after a lot of googling I managed to find out the equivalent HTTP request of that CURL command.

Here is the command -

```
http://testclient1:testpass1@localhost/oauth2-server/token.php?grant_type=password&username=bshaffer&password=brent123
```